# Grails Synchronize forms when data change in database

Tags: grails, asynchronous, grails-orm

When a table is updated in a system by som event that has nothing to do with grails, we want to update the contents of a form if there is a user logged into this form.

Say that a production manager will update the production cost on a product. This change is done in one system which then propagate to other systems where a new price is calculated. This price is displayed on a sellers screen using grails but without this synchronization he has to update his screen to see the new price. This is a simple example but I use just to explain what I want.

Is that possible with grails?

Comment: https://objectpartners.com/2015/06/10/websockets-in-grails-3-0/